# return DTO from WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Haven't managed to find any posts covering this aspect unfortunately.

I created a WebAPI app (ASP.NET Core 2.1) and utilize [NSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag) which I use to auto-generate typescript service proxies.

I've seen code examples where `JsonResult` & `ActionResult` is returned by controller action.

DTOs normally belong in **Service Layer**, so I wonder if it's okay to use them as controller action output.

**I wonder if it is correct to return DTO from controller action.**

*Controller*:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize]
public class EntryController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEntryService _entryService;

    public EntryController(
        IEntryService entryService
        )
    {
        _entryService = entryService;
    }

    public async Task<List<EntryDto>> GetMany(long id)
    {
        var result = await _entryService.GetMany(id);
        return result;
    }
}
```

*Service*:

```
public class EntryService : BaseService, IEntryService
{
    private readonly IEntryHighPerformanceService _entryHighPerformanceService;

    public EntryService(
        AppDbContext context,
        IEntryHighPerformanceService entryHighPerformanceService,
        SessionProvider sessionProvider
        ) : base(
              context,
              sessionProvider
              )
    {
        _entryHighPerformanceService = entryHighPerformanceService;
    }

    public async Task<List<EntryDto>> GetMany(long id)
    {
        var dtos = _entryHighPerformanceService.GetByVocabularyId(id);
        return await Task.FromResult(dtos);
    }
}
```

Comment: @vc74 DTOs belong in Service Layer, so I wonder if it's okay to return them from WebAPI controller action (different layers dilemma)

Comment: @Nkosi netcore 2.1. will update my post now.

Comment: @AlexHerman perfect docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> ## `ActionResult<T>` type
>
> ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduces the `ActionResult<T>` return type for Web API controller actions. It
>   enables you to return a type deriving from `ActionResult` or return a
>   specific type. ActionResult offers the following benefits over the
>   IActionResult type:
>
> - The `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute's Type property can be
>     excluded. For example, `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Product))]` is simplified to `[ProducesResponseType(200)]`. The
>     action's expected return type is instead inferred from the `T` in
>     `ActionResult<T>`.
> - Implicit cast operators support the conversion
>     of both `T` and `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`. `T` converts to
>     `ObjectResult`, which means `return new ObjectResult(T);` is
>     simplified to `return T;`.

Taking your controller for example

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<EntryDto>>> GetMany(long id) {
    //lets say we wanted to validate id
    if(id < 1) {
        return BadRequest("id must be greater than zero (0)");
    }

    var result = await _entryService.GetMany(id);
    if(result == null || result.Count == 0) {
        return NotFound(); // returns proper response code instead of null
    }
    return result;
}
```